# admin view error id column

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-admin

I have a database (postgresql). I recreate the model with Python `manage.py` inspectdb. Here the model :

```
class Groupe(models.Model):
    corg = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    cagence = models.CharField(max_length=2)
    cgroupe = models.IntegerField()

class Meta:
     unique_together = ("corg", "cagence","cgroupe")
     managed = False
     db_table = 'groupe'
```

I just add the unique_together (pk in the original table). When I try to access to the admin page of group, I have an error :

> ERREUR:  the columne groupe.id doesn't existe
>   LINE 1: SELECT "groupe"."id", "groupe"."corg", "groupe"."cagence", "...

Any ideas?

Comment: Django models need a primary key. If one is not declared, Django will assume there is an `id` field.

Comment: unique_together doesn't replace the pk ? 
how can i do without changing the db ?

Comment: A field in the model needs to have primary_key=True else django go looking for the id field, I dont think composite keys are doable - but its being worked on here https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/373 but that ticket has been open for 13 years so dont hold your breath